# Wind strength in a massive planet

Tags: science-based, atmosphere, wind

I'm working on this planet that has 1.5x earth's mass, so the gravity is a little stronger, given that the density it's the same. The gravity is 1.15x earth's.
As i don't know how to calculate the mass of the atmosphere in such conditions i assumed that it would be proportional to the planet mass, in other words 1.5x the mass of earth's atmosphere.

| Atmosphere | absolute info (comparing to earth) |
| --- | --- |
| mass | 77,265x10^17kg (1.5) |
| molecular mass | 29,332g/mol (1.01) |
| atm. pressure | 1,3x10^5Pa (1.28) |
| density | 1,581kg/m³ (1.32) |
| N2 | 69,07% (0.885) |
| O2 | 29,88% (1.43) |
| Ar | 0,94% (1) |
| CO2 | 0,105% (2.58) |

| Star | absolute info (comparing to sun) |
| --- | --- |
| mass | 1.4x10^30kg (0.7) |
| luminosity | 0,952x10^26W (0.25) |

| Planet | absolute info (comparing to earth) |
| --- | --- |
| mass | 8.960,4x10^21kg (1,5) |
| surface area | 668,32x10^12m² () |
| albedo | 0.4 (1.33) |
| mean atmosphere surface temperature | 290K (+2°) |
| tropical sea surface temperature | 301-305K |
| temperate sea surface temperature | 389-395K |
| polar sea surface temperature | 275-281K |
| average distance from star | 75,000,000km (0.5) |
| minimum distance from star | 73,475,000km |
| maximun distance from star | 76,525,000km |
| orbital period | 185 planet days |
| rotational period | 20h |

Given this informations, can the wind in this planet be too much destructive?

I'm a little aware about this because i asked about the tides in the same planet and things are going crazy in there...

Comment: None to help me?

Comment: Wind is caused by uneven heating of the planet so you need to give heating information.

Comment: Like the average temperature of the planet? Star info?

Comment: yeah, and any geothermal or other forms of heating. Stuff like hurricanes are also caused by water heating at different rates than ground I believe. So that matters also I think.

Comment: you need min, max, avg distance from sun, year and day length, etc.

Comment: "mass of the atmosphere in such conditions i assumed that it would be proportional to the planet mass" is a very fluffy assumption. there will be some correlation between atmospheric mass and planetary mass, but it is not linear, nor is mass even remotely the only factor to consider. Composition is a bit more linked to mass, and that, too, is a very complex relationship. Consider Earth and Venus. Very similar mass(venus lighter), yet *vastly* differing atmospheres.

Comment: The biggest difference in those two atmospheres is the amount of CO2 and its consequences. Initial CO2 comes from volcanic eruption so it was inside the rocks in both planets mantle. What makes Earth different from Venus is that we had water to stick this CO2 again into the rocks and life evolved to use this carbon to built its structure. The same way N2 is low compared to CO2 in Venus, but imensely higher than the N2 on earth (other important element for life). Of course i can be wrong in my assumptions, but as you can see in the table both Earth and my planet have similar elements quantity.

Comment: Venus had lots of water too, until recently(700-800 million years ago). The water is *still* there, it's just not water anymore. The hydrogen and oxygen have divorced, and are living with other elements now. https://www.universetoday.com/148790/venus-held-onto-its-water-surprisingly-well-during-its-history/

Comment: i've made my math to improve this question, yet i don't have any proper answer...  please, help!

Comment: Actually, the wind is calculated through the temperature difference between day and night, and local air pressure. Often, this changes. But as long as your planet is in the Goldilocks zone, it will have good enough winds (for living, but I don't have the math to do the exact calculations). If you are not planning on having your planet in the Goldilocks Zone, then know that the closer to the star your planet is, the higher the winds will be. The winds will also be higher if your planet is releasing a lot of energy, or VERY far away from the star, like Neptune or Uranus (not as a joke!)

Answer (score 1):

The amount of force exerted by the wind is determined by the density of the atmosphere, and the velocity of the wind.  It takes more energy to accelerate a denser fluid to the same velocity.

Heavier and denser planets tend to hold more fluid down with their stronger gravity, but many other factors influence how much atmosphere a planet has.  Earth could probably have an atmosphere much more like Venus, or much more like  Mars, if its formation and history had been just a little different.

There are so many variables I can imagine, that I would say you can be fairly free here.

Planets with denser atmospheres but a similar amount of energy from their Sun as Earth gets, would have slower winds.  But the winds would press harder compared to winds of similar speed on Earth.  Hard to even compare strength directly.  At 50x Earth's atmospheric pressure, walking against a 10 km/h wind would feel halfway to like swimming against a strong current in water.  You would be able feel the eddies that swish around your hands as you move them through the air, but you could walk against it.  And with modern engineering we could easily construct buildings to resist it.  But gusts of 40 km/h would knock you over with a full body blow, and building to withstand that would require some creative engineering.

A human can actually breathe, in the real world, at such pressures.  It requires very slow acclimatization while slowly lowering the oxygen ratio.